# Serialization file in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a problem with a file management ...

These files I created using serialization but so offline, in java application.

And while trying to deserialize from android application I get an error ...

I guess that will not be supported by not using the same libraries, to serialize am using Java 1.6 while in utilizao desserialización google api 4.0 ...

Any way to fix this?

Or I have to write a small android application and serialize there?

Regards and thanks

kLvin

Comment: Can't you use a more portable format like XML?

Answer (score 0):

Java serialisation is very very brittle and is prone to breaking -   it is good for short term storage  on local systems and  data usually will not survive clas signature changes or change of JVM (you can work around this, but it is difficult). Better solution would be XML or JSON ( less verbose).  There is a lot of libraries which will  [un]marshall your object treet (to|from)  those formats.  Just some choices:

- jackson
- google gson
- xstream

Some rules of thumb for android

- use pull parsing , not a DOM
- watch for library sizes

My personal choice is homebred JSON serializer build on to of stripped down GSON:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer

( also available on maven central )